# Conditional sum after groupby based on value in another column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the dataframe as below.

```html
Cycle Type Count Value
1 1 5 0.014
1 1 40 -0.219
1 1 5 0.001
1 1 100 -0.382
1 1 5 0.001
1 1 25 -0.064
2 1 5 0.003
2 1 110 -0.523
2 1 10 0.011
2 1 5 -0.009
2 1 5 0.012
2 1 156 -0.612
3 1 5 0.002
3 1 45 -0.167
3 1 5 0.003
3 1 10 -0.052
3 1 5 0.001
3 1 80 -0.194
```

I want to sum the 'Count' of all the positive & negative 'Value' AFTER groupby
The answer would something like
1 1 15 (sum of count when Value is positive),
1 1 165 (sum of count when Value is negative),
2 1 20,
2 1 171,
3 1 15,
3 1 135
I think this will work `(grouped.set_index('Count').groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Value'].......` but i am unable to figure out how to specify positive & negative values to `sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, You can try below code,

```
df= pd.DataFrame (data)
df_negative=df[df['Value'] < 0]
df_positive=df[df['Value'] > 0]
df_negative = df_negative.groupby(['Cycle','Type']).Count.sum().reset_index()
df_positive = df_positive.groupby(['Cycle','Type']).Count.sum().reset_index()
df_combine = pd.concat([df_positive,df_negative]).sort_values('Cycle')
df_combine
```